# EventLog - Get available logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-log

Using the following code, I'm able to display all entries listed under the "Application" log:

```
EventLog appLog = new EventLog();
appLog.Log = "Application";
appLog.MachineName = ".";  

foreach (EventLogEntry entry in appLog.Entries)
{
 // process
}
```

Since I have no FTP o RDP access to the server, **is there any way to get a list of all available logs, beside "Application"?** Some logs are standard but new ones can be added by users/applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run:

```
var d = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
        foreach(EventLog l in d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l.LogDisplayName);
        }
```

If you want to see all the names. They are stored in an array.

**EDIT:**
To do work the way you have it set up use:

```
var d = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
        foreach(EventLog l in d)
        {
            foreach (EventLogEntry entry in l.Entries)
            {
                // process
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes - use the static method `EventLog.GetEventLogs`... BEWARE that this needs appropriate permissions... for details and sample code see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht0k516y.aspx

Comment: Is there is any way to get windows event log for a specific source and time like WindowsLog/System last 12 hr like filter present in event viewer with System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLoges(MachineName);